# is_list_member always gives false in tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy

`is_list_member` method of tweepy always gives `False` independent of whether the member belongs to the list or not.

For example:

```
print api.is_list_member('grupolibertaria',
                        'social-tech-analysis',
                        int(api.get_user('srikar67').id))
```

This always gives `False` eventhough I am a member of the list (I am `srikar67`).

Has anyone faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated to be able to successfully invoke `api.is_list_member`:

```
>>> import tweepy
>>> auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
>>> auth.set_access_token(key, secret)
>>> api = tweepy.API(auth)
>>> user = api.get_user('srikar67')
>>> result = api.is_list_member('grupolibertaria', 'social-tech-analysis', user.id)
>>> result.screen_name
>>> u'srikar67'
>>> result.name
u'Srikar Velichety'
```

You can find more about `tweepy` **OAuth** authentication [here](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/auth_tutorial.html#oauth-authentication) and you can register you application at https://dev.twitter.com so you can obtain your *Consumer Key* and *Consumer Secret* plus the *Access Token* and *Acess Token Secret* necessary for *OAuth* authentication.